# Get the SQL management studio date format

Tags: c#, sql, date, ssms

First i insert a date into a textbox, from a SQL Server.

The user can edit the date when needed.

When the 'Save' button is pressed, i need to check if the date in the textbox is valid for SQL.

When i check the date format as 'yyyy-mm-dd' and the date is valid everything is okay.

But when i install my application on an other computer the date can't inserted in the SQL Server Database.

How can i check the date for the needed format...?

Comment: Please try to elaborate more and add some details. Right now is it not quite clear what are you trying to do and what is your problem.

Comment: What does the management studio have to do with the format of the table? Is that where all the data is inserted from? What is the type of the column containing the date?

Comment: I agree with @AndyKorneyev : the question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry i try to add more info! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: If you mean what date format is stored in SQL Server then it's `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: @ChristianBarron No - dates in the database are just dates. The _client_ determines the string representation.

Comment: Please see edit, is this more clear?

Comment: @DStanley they are stored as two ints but I meant generically it is in that format for SQL Server (string representation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing SQL Management Studio with underlying Database. Based on this qualified guess, the answer is simple: C# implements `DateTime` object compatible with all version of SQL Databases. If data is stored as string in DB, then you should use `DateTime.TryParse()` method to find out if it's a valid `DataTime` value. Furthermore, having the valid `DateTime` object you can convert it to a `String` in any desirable format (e.g. `ToShortDateString()`, etc.).  Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Your approch seems to be wrong.
If, in c#, you read a Date from the database in a correct way, you get a DateTime object, not a formatted string.
For sql use for example sqldatareader.getDateTime()